# Wifi keeps dropping and switching to same SSID but different channel.

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, connection-issues

My Wifi keeps dropping when I tried to connect at places where there are multiple connections with the same SSID but having different channels. What it happens is that it will first connect to the SSID, then after 1 second it will disconnect and connect to the same SSID but from another channel. I observe that it does so even if the new connection has a weaker strength then the previous. This will not happen at home where there is only 1 router. Is there any way whereby I can force android to connect and stay without dropping?

My android is 6.0.1, my phone is Samsung A3(2016).

Thank you.